# How can i get the first free ID from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a primary key field ID. I don't want to use Identity because i need to give the User the posibility of manualy choose an ID for the new object. So my idea is:

1. By default in the edit view, the ID field will be 0.
2. If user don't change it, i need to find the first free ID and use it.
3. If the user change the ID, i first need to check if there's another object with that id, and in that case throw an error.
4. If not, use the ID choose by user.
5. create the new object

The question is how to query and SQL Server table to get the firts free ID number?

**Examples 1:**

```
ID
--
1
2
10
```

First free ID is 3

**Examples 2:**

```
ID
--
1
2
3
4
```

First free ID is 5

Is there a way to do that? 
All i can think of is get the min and max value, create a cycle for possible values and then compare with table data, but it involves too many querys to the database.
Thanks!

Comment: *I have a table with a primary key field ID* - meh. If you mess with that field then don't make it primary key. Use just a normal column for this value.

Comment: @juergend . . . Read what the OP wants to do.  It is not "messing with that field".  The OP simply wants to give users the option to choose a value, if possible, and otherwise to get another reasonable value in a range.

Comment: Exactly. Is like a manual implementation of an autonumeric field with the posibility of skip some values.

Comment: @ericpap - Any reason for doing this specifically? I think the solution is just going to be difficult to implement when you can just use something like `IDENTITY` or auto-increment

Comment: There is a reason why identity fields skip values and it has to do with data integrity. Reusing values that were deleted, which would happen in your scenario, is a very dangerous idea. This is the type of requirement you push back to the user telling them it is very risky and not a good practrice.  If you do this make sure you have proper FKs set up in the database or you will, 100% guaranteed, have bad data within a short time. Incidentally how many 0s are you goung to put in from users that don't change them?

Answer (score 10):

You can find the first free id as the first id where there is no "next" value:

```
select coalesce(min(t.id) + 1, 0)
from table t left outer join
     table t2
     on t.id = t2.id - 1
where t2.id is null;
```

EDIT:

If you want to handle "1" as a potential missing value:

```
select (case when min(minid) > 1 then 1 else coalesce(min(t.id) + 1, 0) end)
from table t left outer join
     table t2
     on t.id = t2.id - 1 cross join
     (select min(id) as minid from table t) const
where t2.id is null;
```

Comment: @ericpap . . . Oops.  Somehow a `not` crept into the condition.

Comment: Very good Idea!!! works almost on every scenario. It's doesn't work if: 1) The empty ID is the first of the table (if ID are 2, 3, 4 it gives me 5 as first free). 2) if there is not data on the table it returns null.

Comment: I suggest change to `MIN(ISNULL(t.id, 0)) + 1`

This way, can return 1

Comment: A constructive criticism sir what happens if the table is empty :)

Comment: @M.Ali Yeah, you're right. It's actually `ISNULL(MIN(T.ID), 0) + 1` <- This works if table is empty

Comment: What if we are looking for the free ID from a number, for example, the free ID from 100

Comment: @Fischer . . . You would either add a constant to this value or ask a new question.  *New* questions should be asked as questions, not comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Test Table**

```
CREATE TABLE ID_TABLE(ID INT)
INSERT INTO ID_TABLE VALUES
(1),(2),(10)
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.usp_GetNextValue
@nxt_ID_Wanted INT = 0,
@nxt_ID_Available INT  OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- If user hasnt passed any value get next avilable value
IF (@nxt_ID_Wanted = 0)   
 BEGIN 
          SELECT TOP 1 @nxt_ID_Available  =  ID + 1 
        FROM 
         (
          SELECT   ID , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) AS rn
         FROM ID_TABLE
         )Q
        WHERE ID = rn
        ORDER BY ID DESC

      IF (@nxt_ID_Available IS NULL)
        BEGIN
          SET @nxt_ID_Available = 1;
        END
 END
     -- If user has passed a value check if it exists and raise error
ELSE  IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ID_TABLE WHERE ID = @nxt_ID_Wanted)
 BEGIN

       RAISERROR('Selected ID value already exists',16,1)
       SET @nxt_ID_Wanted = 0;
       RETURN;
 END 
ELSE      -- else just let the user have the value he/she wanted
 BEGIN 
   SET @nxt_ID_Available = @nxt_ID_Wanted;
 END

END
```

**Execute Procedure**

```
DECLARE @ID INT;
EXECUTE dbo.usp_GetNextValue @nxt_ID_Wanted = 6
                             ,@nxt_ID_Available = @ID OUTPUT

SELECT @ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This function gets first free ID for a table in PostgreSQL (PL/pgSQL):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION next_free_id_from(table_name TEXT) 
  RETURNS BIGINT AS
$$
DECLARE
  next_id BIGINT;
BEGIN
  execute 'select rn from (select id, row_number() over (order by id) as rn from ' || quote_ident(table_name) || ') as T where id > rn limit 1' into next_id;
  if next_id is null then
    execute 'select COALESCE(max(id), 0) + 1 from ' || quote_ident(table_name) into next_id;
  end if;
  return next_id;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql' STRICT;
```

Execute:

```
select next_free_id_from('test');
```

Where `test` is a table name. This function call can be placed in `DEFAULT` of the primary key.

Comment: I don't really understand why you answer a request that is seven years old with a PostgreSQL solution where the request is about SQL Server. Your general idea is good by the way, but lacks two cases: 1. With no row in the table you should return 1 as the first available ID. 2. With rows in the table but no gaps you should return max(id) + 1 as the next available ID.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thank you, I was looking for a solution and I wanted to share it. Btw, I have updated my answer to include your suggested fix.