# JPA Union Equivelant Need for Adding Constant to Query Result

Tags: java, sql, jpa, querydsl

I need union equivelant for Union. I know we can do this by joining selections but i couldn't do that for adding constant to query results. Here is my sql

```sql
SELECT MIN(t1.EXAMPLE_NUMBER)
FROM
     (
     SELECT 1 AS EXAMPLE_NUMBER
     UNION ALL
     SELECT EXAMPLE_NUMBER + 1
     FROM selection.SELECTION
     ) t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN selection.SELECTION t2
ON t1.EXAMPLE_NUMBER = t2.EXAMPLE_NUMBER
WHERE t2.EXAMPLE_NUMBER IS NULL;
```

This query need for finding minimum unused integer for the column. Lets say:

### EXAMPLE_NUMBER

1

4

5

I need to get 2 as a result for this case. That is the sql for this. So here is my question:

I use QueryDsl-JPA for this. Since JPA 2, i can't use UNION. So i can't do this sql with querydsl-jpa, i was thinking about go like this:

```java
JPAQuery baseQuery = new JPAQuery(em);

SubQueryExpression handleNumberOne = baseQuery.select(Expressions.constant(1));
SubQueryExpression selectAvailableMinNumber = baseQuery.select(selection.exampleNumber.add(1)).from(selection);
```

baseQuery.union(handleNumberOne, selectAvailableMinNumber); // NO UNION AVAILABLE

Is it any available way to do this with querydsl-JPA? I don't want to include querydsl-sql library just for this reason, I'm looking for JPA style solution. What i tried so for to try adding constant (1 in my case) to result of select query without union. By this way I may able to continue. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to generate all the numbers to get this information.

For all numbers except 1, you can do:

```
select s.example_number + 1
from selection s
where not exists (select 1
                  from selection s2
                  where s2.example_number = s.example_number + 1
                 )
fetch first 1 row only;   -- or limit 1
```

If you also want to get "1" if it doesn't exist, then:

```
select (case when min_en > 1 then 1
             else s.example_number + 1
        end)
from selection s cross join
     (select min(example_number) as min_en from selection) mins
where not exists (select 1
                  from selection s2
                  where s2.example_number = s.example_number + 1
                 )
fetch first 1 row only;   -- or limit 1
```

Comment: Thanks, i have seen your comment in another question, tried to implemented it before this one but couldn't done it with querydsl, since there is no cross join option, can i go without cross join, lets say inner join?

Comment: @cmlonder . . . Yes.  A simple method is `inner join` with `on 1=1`.

Comment: Yes thanks it works but i still have the same problem. Let me explain-> I don't want to use native query, since our app is so dynamic, i don't want to write db specific code etc. I still can't use JPA, while there is no union. Because for this inner join -> INNER JOIN
         (
            SELECT min(SELECTION_NUMBER) AS minid
            FROM selection.SELECTION)  JPA only let me inner join in select and where clauses. I can't use inner join while creating JPA code. Any suggestions?

Comment: @cmlonder . . . Then don't use the SQL tag on the question.

Comment: If we are talking about SO rules, than why you copy/paste your existing solution which is not related to my question directly, instead of referencing existing question url https://stackoverflow.com/a/23549211/3000280?